# Sort by clicking on column not displaying

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to turn on the sort feature on one of my grids.  I've cloned the examples in the Kendo doc, but it never becomes available.

Does it have to be set before or after filters and/or columns?  I found when modifying the filters, it had to be done before setting the columns, otherwise it would go with the default.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per usual, I post a question, and thirty seconds later I found the answer.

The developer who wrote the original code broke everything into functions, and then built the kendo portion from them.  He never added the sortable option to the final build!